# Fatal error: found nil - In calling Web API with JSON

Tags: swift, xcode

Full error: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.
I am trying to get data from Web API service and am not sure where in the program it is getting nil value from.
Program crashes and getting error at line when declaring jsonResult

```
        let urlAsString = "http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north="+northString+"&south="+southString+"&east="+eastString+"&west="+westString+"&username=test" 

        let url = URL(string: urlAsString)!

        let urlSession = URLSession.shared


        let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            var err: NSError?


            let jsonResult = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary //program crashes and gets error here
            if (err != nil) {
                print("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }

            print(jsonResult)

            let setOne:NSArray? = jsonResult["earthquakes"] as? NSArray
            print(setOne?[0]);

            let y = setOne?[0] as? [String: AnyObject]

            let dateTime: String = (y!["datetime"] as? NSString)! as String

            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.date.text = String(dateTime)
            }


        })

        jsonQuery.resume()
```

Comment: `guard let data = data else {return}
        if let jsonResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as NSDictionary {
            
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like data is `nil`. You forcibly tried to set nil value.

```
if let data = data  {
    if let jsonResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as NSDictionary { 

        if let setOne = jsonResult["earthquakes"] as? [NSDictionary] {
            let y = setOne[0] as? [String: AnyObject]
            let dateTime: String = (y!["datetime"] as? String)! as String
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.date.text = String(dateTime)
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Getting error at line when were setOne is declared. Seems like it wants me to force unwrap
(Error: Value of optional type 'Any?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type 'Any')

Comment: 'let setOne:NSArray? = jsonResult["earthquakes"] as? NSArray'

Comment: What is tha value of jsonResult is? That print this line `print(jsonResult)`

Comment: I believe it is a struct with arrays, from the API:
{
    earthquakes =     (
                {
            datetime = "2010-04-04 20:40:41";
            depth = 10;
            eqid = 14607652;
            lat = "32.128";
            lng = "-115.303";
            magnitude = "7.2";
            src = ci;
        },
                {
            datetime = "2019-07-06 03:29:30";
            depth = 17;
            eqid = ci38457511;
            lat = "35.7664986";
            lng = "-117.6047974";
            magnitude = "7.1";
            src = ci;
        },

Answer (score 1):

It crashes because you force unwrap a `nil` value. So `try` with optional instead

replace this line `let jsonResult = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary` with:

```
do {
  if let jsonResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? NSDictionary {

     // Rest of your code here
  }
} catch let error {

}
```

Comment: When I do that, for some odd reason everywhere else where 'jsonResult' is used suddenly becomes an 'unresolved identifier'.....almost like it doesn't exist. Not sure why that is. (Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'jsonResult')

Comment: You have to put the rest of your code inside the do block. Look at @Faysal Ahmed answer